# Autosys job to change the status to success

Tags: autosys

Hi all i tried this code
D:\Apps\tools\autorep\ixpautorep.exe -M sendevent -J jobname -E CHANGE_STATUS -s SUCCESS

But it shows status of event is missing and ignores success

Please help

Comment: The sendevent command looks good, no issues there...
i have not worked on windows agent.. but the sendevent is to be executed in the autosys CLI. 

In Linux server, the autosys path are to be configured and then user can login into the instances and execute autosys commands like autorep / sendevent ...